# Memory allocation troubles SSAS Azure

Tags: azure, process, calculated-columns, partition, azure-analysis-services

Hello guys,

I have a cube on Azure and when I want to process the partitions (using SSMS) I have that error message `Memory error: You have reached the maximum allowable memory allocation for your tier. Consider upgrading to a tier with more available memory.`

The thing is that I still have 20gb free on my instance and one partition is something like 300mb. I think the problem could come from the calculated columns because the process is perfectly working when I don't have those calculated columns.

Any idea on how to solve it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post the DAX for your calculated columns? Can you confirm if you just do ProcessData not ProcessRecalc (to skip calculated columns) it doesn't fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my problem has been solved. I used that calculated column `[column1]&[column2]` to concatenate and it was not working. By changing it into `CONCATENATE([column1];[column2])` it worked perfectly. I guess the `&` was part of the problem for some reason.

Thanks.